# box-shadow to support IE7 and IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I use the following css code to help support box-shadow in IE7 and IE8:

```
 zoom: 1;
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#4a4a4a, Strength=1, Direction=0),
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#4a4a4a, Strength=1, Direction=0),
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#4a4a4a, Strength=1, Direction=90),
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#4a4a4a, Strength=1, Direction=180),
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#4a4a4a, Strength=1, Direction=270),
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(Color='#ffffff');
```

But it slows the performance in IE. But After doing some googling, I found `ie-css3.htc` which I think would be better than the above code. According to the instruction, I have added some style to my block element:

```
 zoom: 1;
 z-index: 9999;
 position: relative;
 behavior: url(ie-css3.htc)
```

which here is my directory structure:

```
css/
      - style.css
      - ie-css3.htc
js/
images/
ie-css3.htc
index.html
```

I also place the `ie-css3.htc` in my site root according to the documentation. However, this does not help anything. I think that I must have made something wrong.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the path to your htc file in your CSS is correct in all situations:

```
 behavior: url(ie-css3.htc)
```

should be

```
 behavior: url(/css/ie-css3.htc)
```

Comment: Doublecheck to make sure the file is in your css directory. If it is in your root directory then use `behavior: url(/ie-css3.htc)`